# Azure batch working directory issue

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-batch, azure-container-registry

I am newbie to Azure batch as well as docker. The problem i am facing is i have created an image based on another custom image in which some files and folders are created at the root level/directory of the container and every thing works fine but when the same image is running in Azure batch task, i dont know where these files and folders are being created because the wd (working directory) folder is empty. Any suggestions please? Thank you. I know the Azure batch does something with the directory structure but i am not clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you're no doubt aware, Batch maps directories into the container (from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-docker-container-workloads#container-settings-for-the-task)):

> All directories recursively below the AZ_BATCH_NODE_ROOT_DIR (the root of Azure Batch directories on the node) are mapped into the container

so for example if you have a resource file on the task, this ends up in the working directory within the container.  However this doesn't mean the container is allowed to write back to the same location on the host (but only within the container).  I would suggest that you take whatever results/output you have generated and upload them into Azure Blob Storage via a Shared Access Signature - this is the usual way to get results from a Batch job even without using Docker.